# Using Validation Helpers (MVC3 + Razor) on fields not readily available from default Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

I have a strange one that I'm having trouble with.

In a nutshell I have a plain view model, say something like:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
  [Required]
  public string MyString {get;set;}
  public int MyNullableInt {get;set;}
}
```

There is an area of the application that needs to serve any number or type of these within a generic container, like:

```
public class MyGenericContainer
{
  public object MyObject {get;set;}
}
```

So, during transport I collect data into 'MyViewModel', stuff it into the 'MyGenericContainer' object.  Other internal things happen along the way and eventually this makes it to rendering.

In the cshtml file I'm having to cast back:

```
MyViewModel MyItem = (MyViewModel)Model.MyObject;
```

All this works a treat.  The UI responds well, fields are editable and postback properly.  The only thing that fails is the Validation Helpers.  That is:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => MyItem.MyString)
```

seems to have no effect, and although 'MyString' is required, the form still posts.  I've also tried '@Html.ValidationMessage("%NAME%")', but have no idea what %NAME% should be in this case.  Any ideas?

Comment: %NAME% should be "MyString"

Comment: Can you show the code of the controller that binds the model and/or updates it and then rewrites to the generic container?

Comment: It's a simple MyObject = MyViewModel